# Is there a SO equivalent of the "witness protection program"?

Tags: support, serial-voting

For about 3 weeks out of the past month I've been the victim of serial downvoting about 2 days per week (i.e. there's no change in rep for days, then in a 30 second period every question I've ever asked on SO and other SE sites gets downvoted). About 40 - 50% of that got corrected by the nightly anti-serial-voting CRON job.

Yesterday I got serial *upvoted*, only to wake up this morning and see that both the upvoting was corrected and there's new serial downvoting. I basically know who the abusers are and that they are using sock puppets / proxies to serial downvote without the CRON job doing anything about it. I guess the serial upvoting was either a coincidence or a new way to mess with me by the same users.

I come here to answer questions and occasionally ask them. I'm sick of the chronic game-playing like this by some users that takes the fun out of using this site.

**Is it possible to get an identity change** (e.g. new user number, as well as new username) to discourage these obsessed sock-puppet loving game-players? Something like the "witness protection program".

Comment: We don't have enough cops for _“witness protection program”_. Also, the cops we're having are super-busy. **identity change** will not solve the problem. _Those_ users can still find you by your posts.

Comment: contact a mod? Or make a new account?

Comment: Flag this for moderator attention. I wouldn't usually suggest that with serial voting, but this seems to be pretty clear and consistent -- hopefully the mods can help out here.

Comment: @Hayt I could make a new account, but I didn't want to lose all my rep thusfar in case I want to put it on my resume some day. I used the Contact Us link and that helped with 1 or 2 individual serial downvoting instances, though I think they got tired of hearing about it every time.

Comment: Did you read the message your flag(s) were declined with? *This is your third request, and we got the other two. They were passed on to Stack Exchange, so if you want to know the status of this, I recommend contacting them directly.* There's not much moderators or the community can do with this - the team that have the tools to look into this have it and it'll be in their queue to be looked at - you just need to be patient I'm afraid.

Comment: @Tushar Argh, yea I guess they could still find me if they kept a list of my past questions. So there's no permanent solution (just ask for help each time)? Should I delete this question or leave it posted?

Comment: and depending on who the people are and if they just have a problem with you personally, or with a certain view you hold and thus also targeting others. A new account could result with just the same problem (but that depends on the specifics here. You don't need to answer that just think about it). *Witness protection* would also require you to be restricted in some ways (if we take the word literally)

Comment: @Hayt I could limit my movements to some small town in the midwest

Comment: @Hack-R just to note - I've reached out to the user that I'm fairly certain is doing this and asked them to desist - whether they do or not is another thing but action will be taken if not. In the mean time, while I realise it's frustrating, just shrug it off and don't worry about it. The SE team will look into it in more depth than mods can as soon as they can, okay?

Comment: @Hack-R Keep the question, someone else may think of the same thing and best it be answered here rather than a second one pop up for the same reason

Comment: "I'm sick of the chronic game-playing" Say the guy bumping in active tab old question for a few char edit to get a gold badge... #Facepalm

Comment: To complement my previous comment, serial downvoting is not welcome. I just mean you're seems really playing a game here and giving too much importance to reputation points. Raising a mod flag is enough and they do they work. Raising multiples flags and opening a meta against it sounds not in my opinion.

Comment: @Tensibai - Ummm, the "guy" who said "I'm sick of the chronic game-playing" wasn't the *person* who edited the question.

Comment: @Comintern I'm talking about the OP recent edit activity to get the "Copy Editor" Gold badge, not the editor of this question. (And an old question is at least few weeks old in this context)

Comment: @Tensibai - You mean... like... a week ago? How is that even relevant to the question being asked here?

Comment: @Comintern As much of a game playing is relevant to SO. How could someone game playing SO to get badges can be sick of others game playing ? This sentence is irrelevant in the question, we agree.

Comment: Wow, who has that kind of time to commit to serially messing with someone like that?  He/she/they must *really* be mad.  What did you do to set these guys off?

Comment: Do you know why they're targeting you?  Is it because your name is "Hack-R"?  That's honestly kind of asking for trouble in my opinion...

Comment: Also possibly relevant, I visited the website in your profile (hack-r.com) and webroot blocked it for known malicious content.

Comment: @Scott - I think that's a webroot issue... note that the OP is most active in the R tag. "They were asking for it" really isn't a justification for much of anything.

Comment: Perhaps.  I just think calling yourself "hacker" is asking for unwanted attention.  Is it witty? Sure. But if you really want to stop being targeted at least it's somewhere to start.

Comment: And he's stated that he knows who is doing it, but to my knowledge still hasn't said why.  It might be good information to know.

Comment: @Scott I cant imagine that telling him that his name is bad is the right solution.  Thats victim blaming at its finest. Something akin to... "Well of course you were assaulted, you shouldnt wear dresses that short"

Comment: @Scott - "If you really want to stop being targeted"?  Seriously?  What other behaviors do you think justify serial downvoting?  Maybe you should post that question on Meta to gauge the community response.

Comment: @Tushar If you have enough cops, you don't need a witness protection program (relocating witnesses and changing their identity, so that they can be protected from criminals without a lot of policing). You can just swarm the witnesses with cops right there where they are, under their current identities.  If SO had the equivalent of "enough cops" it would stop all serial downvoting in real-time.

Comment: You can change your account name yourself once every month or something like that

Comment: Why are these people “attacking” you?

Comment: @MartinBean My version of the story is that they hate me for loving freedom and equal rights and b/c they are jelly. OK, seriously it's just b/c I was on a mission to earn certain badges and boost my rep so I started spending every free minute for months in a certain tag where they're the big fish and they were (IMO) rude/abusive so I tried to call them out and that really made them mad. It's no big deal really tho, I can understand a bunch of guys kind of competing in the same tag could get frustrated w/ each other, but I just wanted them to move on after a while and leave me be, etc.

Comment: Why don't you ignore them?

Comment: @jwg I try but this question was more about the serial voting. I think some mods looked into it after this and took care of it fortunately.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**TL;DR: Yes, but** you'd be starting all over again, at 1 rep.

If you want to get a new user ID and/or username, you can simply create a new account. There's no rule against that; multiple accounts aren't explicitly supported, but they're not by any means forbidden.

**However**, doing that means that you'd be starting afresh. No record of your posts, 1 rep, no privileges. Any attempt to re-associate your posts with your new account or to restore your rep (even if the developers were willing to invest the time to do that) would make it trivial for anyone targeting you to find you again.

**Instead**, talk to a moderator. I can see from the comments that action has already been taken in this case, so I include this here for reference: if you're being serially downvoted, and the script isn't taking care of all of it, then you should either (a) post on meta, asking a moderator to check it out, or (b) flag one of your posts for moderator attention and ask the moderators to check on it. Moderators have tools to identify users who are serially voting on your content - up or down - and can take action against anyone who's part of it.

**N.B.:** If you do decide to create a brand new account and start again, *don't* be tempted to upvote this account's posts in the name of "balancing it out". That will get your votes detected and reversed by the algorithm, and bring a moderator or two down on your head for doing exactly that which you're concerned about here. Multiple accounts are fine - as long as they don't interact or vote for one another.

Comment: Another concern is voting on third party posts. You should not use two accounts to vote on the same posts. But the OP has the Electorate badge on SO, so voted a lot. They probably don't know everything they've voted on anymore. One would need to delete the original account, to undo at least the recent votes.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Sure, in theory that's an issue. But in reality, there's enough stuff on SO that you're unlikely to hit the same post twice by accident - and if you do, one duplicate vote doesn't harm anything much.

Comment: A user who starts anew, is still likely to be active in the same tags. And encounter many of the same posts.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I disagree. You'll be in the same tags, sure, but unless those tags have particularly low activity, you'll be looking at new posts each day, rather than going back to old posts that have been answered now.

Comment: @ArtOfCode:  Some tags have "canonical" questions that keep coming up.  They'd be especially easy to re-encounter when looking to flag a duplicate question, and hard to remember without the little orange up-arrow.  Someone who's been active for a couple years would have to remember a new rule: "never upvote old posts".

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase That or constantly be logging into their old account to check if they've voted on a given post; which would be pretty annoying.

Comment: I seriously doubt a few "double" upvotes would matter especially on canonical posts.

Comment: advice "talk to a moderator..." would better be expanded with "...and prepare to wait for quite a long time, possibly for a several months" (that was my own experience with similar case)

Answer (score -14):

If it's the same user who is constantly downvoting your answers, you should report this person to the moderators as abusing the rating system. If they are really downvoting questions / answers that are very solid, it should be obvious.

If it's different people doing the downvoting, your answers just might be chronically mediocre.

Comment: How would he know "if it's the same user"? You have no way to track down your downvoter - do you?

Comment: @matt - From the question, OP seems fairly confident he knows who is doing the downvoting.

Comment: .. Am I allowed to believe that this answer was both generalistic and gratuitously hostile? A quick glance at the answers OP provided is enough to dismiss at least the last sentence.

Comment: I concur with that @EricWu (the answer quality part)

Comment: @RichScriven This is about the answer, not the OP's question. The OP has no hard evidence, so advising the OP to "report this person" seems like bad advice. I have been serially downvoted after a spat, but _post hoc_ is not _propter hoc_; I would _never_ "report this person" on such a flimsy basis.